# Need to find engagement from existing Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I have a Data Extension in SFMC where I've captured customer purchase data, let's call it "cust_purch_12mo" and right now it only contains the customer email address and purchase date.

I am trying to create a query that will populate another data extension, called "6mo_engage", where it references "cust_purch_12mo" and returns only those customers that have open/clicked (engaged) with an email from the past 6 months.

I'm fairly new to SQL as a whole and was able to get results using the following SQL, However, I don't feel as if it's actually referencing "cust_purch_12mo" to get its results and instead is returning results based on all customer data.

```
Select 
    a.OrderHeader_EmailAddress
,   Max(c.EventDate) as Customer_Click_Date

From 
_Click c

Inner Join
[cust_purch_12mo] a

On
c.SubscriberKey = a.OrderHeader_EmailAddress

Where
CAST(c.eventdate AS DATE) >= CAST(DATEADD(day, -183, GETDATE()) AS DATE)


Group By 
    c.eventdate
,   a.OrderHeader_EmailAddress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So assuming that you have your email address as your primary key this is what I would do:

```
SELECT OrderHeader_EmailAddress
FROM cust_purch_12mo
WHERE OrderHeader_EmailAddress IN
(
    SELECT SubscriberKey
    FROM _Open
)
```

You mentioned that you wanted to measure engagement, that's why I used the open instead of click data view. You don't need the where clause for the dates as the data views only hold 6 months of data anyways. Also if you're in a child account use the `ENT.` prefix for `ENT._Open`. Lmk if it works.

Comment: Thank you @intern. I will try this out but I do need to filter down to clicks, rather than just opens for this specific request.

Comment: Thanks again @intern. I was able to get this to work both with seeing what _Open produced as well as _Click as they are pretty different results.